# Umbraco and returning PartialView with invalid model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

So I have a controller that derives from SurfaceController.

I have a partial view.

When the user hits submit, it posts to the controller method. This method will do some validation on the model and other business logic.

If it fails, I want to return the model back to the partial view showing the error message. I use in this case ModelState.AddModelError to add the error to the model state.

I do this and I don't see the error at all on the partialview area.

Any ideas why? I don't understand why when doing:

return PartialViewResult(model);

or even:

return CurrentUmbracoPage();

it does not show the errors.

here is the code I am using...

```
[HttpPost]

public PartialViewResult Login(UserLogin ReceivedModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                return PartialView(ReceivedModel);
            }

            try
            {

                var returnedData = someClass.DoSomething(ReceivedModel);

                if (!returnedData.Valid)

                {

                   ModelState.AddModelError("Problem....");

                   return PartialView(ReceivedModel);


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex);
                return CurrentUmbracoPage();
            }
}
```

So when I do return PartialView(ReceivedModel) (or return CurrentUmbracoPage()), it then displays the page but does not show the error.

Answer (score 0):

do you have

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.xxxx, "Required field")

in your view?

Comment: tried it with and without. eventually figured out the problem. basically the view was not being rendered as Html.Partial but instead Html.Action. This caused problems.